# "Request signature does not match" error in SQS when running in .NET Framework. but not .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, amazon-sqs

I have a component in a multi-targeted assembly that uses Amazon SQS. In my unit test project, running in both .NET Core 3.1 and .NET Framework 4.6.1, I can successfully send messages to SQS when running in .NET Core, but in .NET Framework, I'm getting a 403 Forbidden error, "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."

Debugging, I've confirmed that the keys are correct (the values of the properties of AmazonSQSClient.Credentials._lastCredentials match those in my credentials file).
[image: This seems like it should work]
(The credentials shown in this screenshot are only temporary.)

I've read through ["Troubleshooting AWS Signature Version 4 errors"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-troubleshooting.html) but the request signature is being calculated by the AWS code, not me. In fact, ["Authenticating Requests (AWS Signature Version 4)"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html) says, "If you use the AWS SDKs (see Sample Code and Libraries) to send your requests, you don't need to read this section because the SDK clients authenticate your requests by using access keys that you provide."

I've updated to the latest versions of all AWS packages that I'm using. I can't tell if I'm doing something wrong here, or if this a bug in the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in my code, the logic for when it was using .NET Framework did not properly create the queue URL. However, the error message about the request signature had me on a wild goose chase for a few days.